# How to change array variable name dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am working for some common method in javascript, for that i have to call array dynamically.

```
 var ddlText, ddlValue, ddl, lblMesg, ddlTextCacheList_Designation, ddlValueCacheList_Designation, ddlTextCacheList_Scale, ddlValueCacheList_Scale;
 function cacheDes() {
      
        var listDes = document.getElementById("<%=List_Designation.ClientID %>");
        ddlTextCacheList_Designation = new Array();
        ddlValueCacheList_Designation = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < listDes.options.length; i++) {
            ddlTextCacheList_Designation[ddlTextCacheList_Designation.length] = listDes.options[i].text;
            ddlValueCacheList_Designation[ddlValueCacheList_Designation.length] = listDes.options[i].value;

        }

        
    }


    function cacheScale() {
        var listScale = document.getElementById("<%=List_Scale.ClientID %>");
        ddlTextCacheList_Scale = new Array();
        ddlValueCacheList_Scale = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < listScale.options.length; i++) {
            ddlTextCacheList_Scale[ddlTextCacheList_Scale.length] = listScale.options[i].text;
            ddlValueCacheList_Scale[ddlValueCacheList_Scale.length] = listScale.options[i].value;

        }


    }

    window.onload = function () {
        cacheDes();
        cacheScale();
    };
```

I want to call array ddlTextCacheList_Scale or ddlTextCacheList_Designation for same method as we know 'ddlTextCacheList_' is common only we need to put 'Scale' or 'Designation' dynamicaaly by passing parameter.

**Add:**
I get some errors:
[image]

Comment: they are global both, so you can use `window[arrName]` syntax

Comment: but better to use one object with both arrays: `{texts: [], values: []}`

Comment: i want to pass just 'Designation' or 'scale' through parameter and that name should be concat in 'ddlTextCacheList_' there fore appropriate array must be call. i.e. if i say Designation than ddlTextCacheList_Designation and ddlValueCacheList_Designation must call

Comment: `window['ddlValueCacheList_'+param]`

Comment: but better move out your business logic from variable names - make object with keys: `{Scale: [{text: '', value: 1}, {text: '', value: 2}]}`

Comment: @vp_arth window['ddlValueCacheList_'+param] is good option. can you suggest how can i remove some or say 0th element from that array ?

Comment: `arr.splice(index, 1)` can be used to remove index'th element from an array

Comment: but you can just change iteration start from 0 to 1 in your loops :)

Comment: ya but i wanna do that parametrized... means if i pass 'Designation' than 0th element must be remove from 'ddlValueCacheList_Designation' array. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to improve your cache to store all in one object to easy access...
For example:

```
var CacheStorage = {};
function cache(key, list) {
  CacheStorage[key] = list.map(function(option){
    return {text: option.text, value: option.value};
  });
}
function del(key, index) {
  CacheStorage[key].splice(index, 1);
}

cache('Scale', getElementByID('...').options);
cache('Designation', getElementByID('...').options);
del('Designation', 0);
```

Comment: just want to ask... is there need to call cache on window.onload  event  ?

Comment: It depends... it need, if your lists can be not loaded in the call time.

Comment: yes i need. can you please tell me how to do that in this scenario

Comment: i am asking because this cache function become parametrized now. So i dont have any idea how to call this onload

Comment: no worries i did it. But its an exception   'JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map''

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map.call(list, function...);` for collections, which are not array...

Comment: something gonna wrong :(   check image added in your suggestion

Comment: You just need to add checks, that your cache has `key` key and `index` index before trying delete it.

Comment: @MaciejPyszyński, @krillgar, @GerarddeVisser, please check edits which you approve before click `Approve` button later.